# Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I try to use the Kotlin MPP(Multiplatform) to develop a shared library between Android and iOS. But I face the problem about threading in iOS. For my application in iOS, I establish the object in main thread but it probably calls the function in the other thread and throw this exception as following:

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared example.api.DrivingBehaviorDetector@397cba8 from other thread
        at 0   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x00000001037619d7 kfun:kotlin.Throwable.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.Throwable + 87
        at 1   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x000000010375bca5 kfun:kotlin.Exception.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.Exception + 85
        at 2   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x000000010375b9a5 kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException.<init>(kotlin.String?)kotlin.RuntimeException + 85
        at 3   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x0000000103781395 kfun:kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException.<init>(kotlin.String)kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException + 85
        at 4   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x0000000103782568 ThrowIllegalObjectSharingException + 744
        at 5   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x00000001037d72bc _ZNK27BackRefFromAssociatedObject19ensureRefAccessibleEv + 76
        at 6   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x00000001037c97c3 -[KotlinBase toKotlin:] + 35
        at 7   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x00000001037e3ef1 Kotlin_ObjCExport_refFromObjC + 65
        at 8   DrivingBehaviorDetector             0x00000001037c4e37 objc2kotlin.125 + 167
        at 9   Test                                0x000000010340224d $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 45 (/Users/james/Documents/Projects/go/TestMPPforiOS/<compiler-generated>:<unknown>)
        at 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000103959dd4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
        at 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010395ad48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        at 12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010396c460 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 819
        at 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010396cb96 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 132
        at 14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5245f6b3 _pthread_wqthread + 583
        at 15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff5245f3fd start_wqthread + 13
(lldb)
```

I survey the solution in these articles:

Immutability in Kotlin/Native: [Immutability in Kotlin/Native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/immutability.html)

Coroutines and Immutability of K/N: [Coroutines and Immutability of K/N](https://medium.com/quick-code/kotlin-native-ios-a1a73d7390fe).

The entrance of my API(shared library) as following:

```
class DrivingBehaviorDetector (
    private var gravity:Vector?,
    private var front:Vector?,
    onGravityOrFrontChanged: ((newGravity: Vector?, newFront: Vector?, timestamp: Long) -> Unit)?,
    onDrivingEventDetected: ((event: DrivingEvent) -> Unit)?
) {

    private val lowPassFilter = LowPassFilter()
    private val accProcessor = AccProcessor(gravity, front, onGravityOrFrontChanged, onDrivingEventDetected)

    init {
        gravity = gravity?.toCoreUnit()
        front = front?.toCoreUnit()
    }

    fun addData(data:Acceleration) {
        val rawAcc = data.toCoreUnit()
        val filterAcc = lowPassFilter.lowPass(rawAcc)
        accProcessor.addData(filterAcc)
    }

    fun addData(data:List<Acceleration>) {
        for(acc in data) {
            addData(acc)
        }
    }
}
```

We can notice the API is so simple as feeding a lot of data and callback the results from some calculations. But in the iOS throw the exception and code as following:

```swift
let drivingBehaviorDetector = DrivingBehaviorDetector(gravity: nil, front: nil, onGravityOrFrontChanged: { (newGravity, newFront, timestamp) in
    print("newGravity = \(newGravity)")
    print("newFront = \(newFront)")
}) { (event) in
    print("event = \(event.description())")
}

let acc1 = Acceleration(vector: Vector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0))
let acc2 = Acceleration(vector: Vector(x: 0, y: 100, z: 0))

drivingBehaviorDetector.addData(data: acc1)

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    drivingBehaviorDetector.addData(data: acc2)
}
```

The only one solution I can imagine is forcing to use API in the same thread but this seems to a little strange. Is it possible to solve this issue by modifying the shared library. Because mu usage is simple as only one "DrivingBehaviorDetector" but it could be calling the "addData" function in the different thread. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

With Kotlin/Native one must explicitly define correct concurrency behavior, to avoid races. In this particular case, there are several choices:

- make `drivingBehaviorDetector` instance frozen (by calling `freeze()` in the constructor, for example), and implement `addData()` using concurrency-safe mechanisms, such as linked list of frozen sample data or use Swift collection instance
- think over thread affinity in your application, and decide who is the owner of `drivingBehaviorDetector` instance, instantiate and use this instance only in that context/thread/queue enforcing that by dispatcher APIs
- have dedicated worker/coroutine processing samples and send samples to that worker, like is being done in video sample player at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/8f7ebe7f511d5700cf559c854f9202bf55240e11/samples/videoplayer/src/videoPlayerMain/kotlin/DecoderWorker.kt#L384

Comment: For the 1st choice, there are no freeze() method in the Swift, but I instantiate the detector in the Swift. However, If I choose this, I should freeze every object using in the detector? This seems to be a little complicated. BTW, can you explain more about concurrency-safe mechanisms? I thought one of the benefit of Kotlin-Multiplatform is shared codes between platforms, but this solution seems to be re-written everything for iOS specifically.

Comment: One can have `freeze()` call in init/constructor of the class after all mutating inits happened. This is recursive operation, so all reachable objects will be frozen. Using expect/actual mechanism freeze operation itself could be abstracted out, rest of the code will be multiplatform.

Answer (score 0):

Enable **kotlin.native.binary.memoryModel=experimental** in gradle.properties