# Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException:

Tags: kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm still relatively new to KMM and a project I'm working on keeps yeilding this error:

```
Uncaught Kotlin exception: kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException: illegal attempt to access non-shared dev.mrbe.haarShared.HaarSDK@abc468 from other thread
    at 0   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x00000001020909a1 kfun:kotlin.Throwable#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 97 (/opt/buildAgent/work/c5a36d4d82b914cf/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Throwable.kt:24:56)
    at 1   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x0000000102089dad kfun:kotlin.Exception#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 93 (/opt/buildAgent/work/c5a36d4d82b914cf/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:23:58)
    at 2   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x0000000102089fcd kfun:kotlin.RuntimeException#<init>(kotlin.String?){} + 93 (/opt/buildAgent/work/c5a36d4d82b914cf/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/Exceptions.kt:34:58)
    at 3   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x00000001020c140d kfun:kotlin.native.IncorrectDereferenceException#<init>(kotlin.String){} + 93 (/opt/buildAgent/work/c5a36d4d82b914cf/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/Runtime.kt:31:50)
    at 4   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x00000001020c508f ThrowIllegalObjectSharingException + 623 (/opt/buildAgent/work/c5a36d4d82b914cf/kotlin/kotlin-native/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/native/concurrent/Internal.kt:115:11)
    at 5   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x00000001022a1b52 _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_128throwIllegalSharingExceptionEP9ObjHeader + 34
    at 6   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x00000001022a389d _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_136terminateWithIllegalSharingExceptionEP9ObjHeader + 13
    at 7   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x00000001022a39b5 _ZNK27BackRefFromAssociatedObject3refIL11ErrorPolicy3EEEP9ObjHeaderv + 133
    at 8   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x0000000102070e25 -[KotlinBase toKotlin:] + 21
    at 9   kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x0000000102295058 Kotlin_ObjCExport_refFromObjC + 88
    at 10  kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule     0x0000000102040676 objc2kotlin.505 + 230
    at 11  haar                                0x00000001006b3181 $s4haar11MyViewModelC10addBooking7bookingySo031KotlinmultiplatformsharedmoduleF0C_tYaFTY0_ + 273 (/Users/essienedim/Desktop/HAAR /haar/haar/ContentView.swift:422:33)
    at 12  libswift_Concurrency.dylib          0x00007ff833c40426 _ZN5swift34runJobInEstablishedExecutorContextEPNS_3JobE + 310
    at 13  libswift_Concurrency.dylib          0x00007ff833c411bd _ZL17swift_job_runImplPN5swift3JobENS_11ExecutorRefE + 77
    at 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001014dfe77 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 87
    at 15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001014def27 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 997
    at 16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001014f1e77 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 414
    at 17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001014f2b17 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 278
    at 18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff833e39f8a _pthread_wqthread + 256
    at 19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff833e38f57 start_wqthread + 15
CoreSimulator 857.7 - Device: iPhone 14 Pro (C24AA3AD-B79D-437E-BCB7-A15C83C0F412) - Runtime: iOS 16.0 (20A360) - DeviceType: iPhone 14 Pro
(lldb)
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180941/uncaught-kotlin-exception-kotlin-native-incorrectdereferenceexception-illegal) and some other posts on this but when I try using the `freeze()` method, I keep getting an `Unresolved reference: freeze`. I can't seem to figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong and honestly, what I should be freezing exactly.

Here's the function that seems to be triggering this Exception:

```
func addBooking(booking: Booking) async {
        await  sdk.postBooking(booking: booking)
    }
```

The SDK class is initialise in the view model like so:

```
class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
let sdk: HaarSDK

...

init(sdk: HaarSDK) {
    self.sdk = sdk
    ...
          
  }
}
```

Main View:

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel: MyViewModel
    
    init() {
        
        let sdk =   HaarSDK(databaseDriverFactory: DatabaseDriverFactory())
        
       let viewModel = MyViewModel(sdk: sdk)
       _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
     }

...
    }
```

SDK class (Kotlin):

```
class HaarSDK(databaseDriverFactory: DatabaseDriverFactory) {
    private val database = Database(databaseDriverFactory)
    private val api = HaarApi()

    ...

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    suspend fun postBooking(booking: Booking) {
        api.sendBooking(booking)
    }
  ...
}
```

Database:

```
internal class Database(databaseDriverFactory: DatabaseDriverFactory) {
    private val database by lazy {
        AppDatabase(databaseDriverFactory.createDriver())
    }
    private val dbQuery = database.appDatabaseQueries
...
}
```

API class:

```
class HaarApi {
    private val httpClient = HttpClient {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            val json = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }
            serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json)
        }
...

  suspend fun sendBooking(booking: Booking) {
        val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.post(BOOKING_ENDPOINT) {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            body = booking
        }
...
}
```

Comment: You are creating the SDK on your main thread, but then you are accessing it from an async scope. This is what is causing the problem. So to fix this, you would need to make sure that whatever thread it is created on, is the only place it is accessed from. This can be tricky to accomplish, but the "Actor" pattern is a way to accomplish this. Second, freeze can only be added in ios Platform specific code, I am assuming the code you have shared is all in a common code.

Comment: This is not likely the cause of your issue, but note that `StateObject(wrappedValue:)` runs an autoclosure, *once* for the View. You should not do work creating your view model outside of that autoclosure.